Sending a gmail message only once using a message id
I am trying to make sure that my system doesn't send duplicate Gmail emails. The message class seems to have a field id that I can set using setId method. My current idea would be to generate a UUID value. Would this ensure that Gmail will de-dupe the messages with the same message id?
